# Draw graph of f(1-|x|) from graph of f(x)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

i need help in

Draw graph of $f(1-|x|)$ from graph of $f(x)$, applying translations

Thank you

Comment: I am closing this question as it does not meet the standards for this site. I encourage you to read other upvoted content, read the help section, and read [how to ask](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two cases: $x \geq 0$, $x < 0$.

When $x \geq 0$, the function turns into $f(-x+1)$, which is a reflection about $y$-axis($-x$) and shifted $1$ unit to the right($+1$).

When $x < 0$, the function turns into $f(x+1)$, which is $f$ shifted left $1$ unit.

Comment: if I move one unit to the left and then a reflection on and changes the result

Comment: how important is the order, reflect, translation

Comment: @Julio Yarasca Reflection goes before translation.